# Desktop icons getting realigned and overlapped

Tags: icons

I have a couple of icons on the Ubuntu Desktop (11.10). Every time after reboot the icons get realigned and icons are overlayed on one another. I have to adjust the icons again and again after reboot. BTW, I am Ubuntu 11.10 on Dell Mini.

How do I solve this?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is a bug [#40872](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/40872) as reported on Launchpad quite some time ago.

If you believe this is not a duplicate of that bug you should file another one.